# Swift 3 sort jsonArray

Tags: arrays, json, swift, sorting

please can you tell me how to sort (descending, ascending) multiple arrays of "BonusCard" in "bonusCardsArray" on the basis of its "currentPoints" values.

```
//Array to sort according to "currentPoints" 
var bonusCardsArray = [BonusCard]()

//basis class
class BonusCard {

  var companyName             : String
  var bonusCardDescription    : String
  var currentPoints           : Int
  var bonusCardType           : Int


  init(companyName: String, bonusCardDescription: String,    
  currentPoints: Int, bonusCardType: Int) {

      self.companyName = companyName
      self.bonusCardDescription = bonusCardDescription
      self.currentPoints = currentPoints
      self.bonusCardType = bonusCardType
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort in place (ascending order w.r.t. to the `currentPoints` property), make use of the [`sort(by:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2296801-sort)

```
bonusCardsArray.sort { $0.currentPoints < $1.currentPoints }
```

Or, to create a new array; the sorted version of the original one, make use of the [`sorted(by:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2296815-sorted)

```
let sortedfBonusCardsArray = bonusCardsArray
    .sorted { $0.currentPoints < $1.currentPoints }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write the following code.

- for descending

  bonusCardsArray.sorted({ $0. currentPoints > $1. currentPoints })
- for ascending

  bonusCardsArray.sorted({ $0. currentPoints < $1. currentPoints })

Comment: Thanks a lot, mates. Could not imagine that a one-liner can do so much:-)